# Payment Gateway integration on selecting user profiles

Tags: 7, commerce, ubercart

I am working on a project where human resource agents can view a list of job applicants. On each job applicant profiles theres a **Confirm job applicant** link visible only to human resource agents.
Once the HR agent clicks on **Confirm job applicant** link, the control should go to a payment gateway and after the HR successfully does the payment, the job applicant should get confirmed by that HR agent.

I was thinking to use ubercart module to handle all the payment transaction, but is ubercart the best choice for this type of workflow as theres no product shopping cart model here.

Is there any other module which can be used for the above workflow?

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) would probably be a better choice. I've used it on two non-standard ecommerce systems and it works well. It's very flexible and the rules integration would allow you to do things like comfirm and email applicant on order completion.

Comment: Is it possible to integrate payment gateway integration without creating products in the site?

Comment: No, you'd need to add products. But you can add them to the cart programmatically. Sounds like a custom module would be your best option if you only wanna collect payment. What payment gateway are you using?

Comment: Yea, so programmatically I am adding the product and taking user to checkout form. I am using adyen payment gateway. Its integrated and working well :) [\n] Then only doubt I had was will it be possible to create an order without adding any product to the order.